# Redirecting to a page using restful methods?

Tags: java, rest, redirect

I've created a page which asks user to fill some form fields and when he submits, the form is sent to a Restful method which you can see below:

```
@POST
@Path("addUser")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void addUser(@FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormParam("password") String password,
        @FormParam("id") String id,
        @FormParam("group_name") String groupName,
        @FormParam("authority_name") String authorityName,
        @FormParam("authority_id") String authorityId
        )
{
    //Something will be done here
}
```

How can I redirect the user at the end of this function to (let's say) index.jsp?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a URI using `javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder` that maps the parameters and other data you want to preserve. Then use `Response.temporaryRedirect` to return a redirect to the client and pass it the URI you’ve built.

Comment: This class you introduced 'UriBuilder' has so many unimplemented methods. One cannot simply instantiate an instance from it.
I used 'java.net.URI location = new java.net.URI("../index.jsp");
Response.temporaryRedirect(location);' and still nothing happens.

Comment: I think we should add a code line like this:     
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.temporaryRedirect(location).build());

Answer (score 14):

change your code like this, the addUser() should return a Response Object

```
public Response addUser(@FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormParam("password") String password,
        @FormParam("id") String id,
        @FormParam("group_name") String groupName,
        @FormParam("authority_name") String authorityName,
        @FormParam("authority_id") String authorityId
        )
{
    //Something will be done here

    java.net.URI location = new java.net.URI("../index.jsp?msg=A_User_Added");
    return Response.temporaryRedirect(location).build()

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally I come to this conclusion that there are no other way than what I did:
So here is my solution:

```
try {
        java.net.URI location = new java.net.URI("../index.jsp?msg=A_User_Added");
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.temporaryRedirect(location).build());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

By adding this block to my code, I got what I needed. Hope it helps you as well.

Answer (score 2):

See below the usage of redirecting in web services:

```
public class LoginWebService {

    @POST
    @Path("/check")
    public Response checkDetails(@FormParam("name") String name,@FormParam("pass") String pass ) throws URISyntaxException  {

        URI uri = new URI("/login/success");
        URI uri2= new URI("http://localhost:9090/NewWebServiceproject/new/login/failure");

        if(name.equals("admin") && pass.equals("pass"))
    //@Path("http://localhost:8010/NewWebServiceproject/new/login/success");
            {
            return Response.temporaryRedirect(uri).build();
            //Response.seeOther(uri);
            //return Response.status(200).entity("user successfully login").build();
            }
        else
        {
            return Response.temporaryRedirect(uri2).build();
            //Response.seeOther(uri2);
            //return Response.status(200).entity("user logon failed").build();
            }
    }
    @POST
    @Path("/success")
    public Response successpage()
    {
    return Response.status(200).entity("user successfully login").build();
    }
    @POST
    @Path("/failure")
    public Response failurepage()
    {
    return Response.status(200).entity("user logon failed").build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not good idea to use the "WebApplicationException" in order to redirect the request. in Jersey (2.4.1) you should be able to redirect the request via the normal servlet way, (request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher().forward() or just response.sendRedirect())

The following is how Jersey process the request

```
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      requestScope.runInScope
           final ContainerResponse response = endpoint.apply(data)
                  methodHandler.invoke(resource, method, args);
           Responder.process(ContainerResponse);
```

That **methodHandler** is your REST service class, **method** is the function in that service class.

The step to redirect page become straightforward

1. Get the (request, response) through Jersey injection (@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) in class field or function parameter
2. Call request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher() to get the dispatcher for "forward"
   or use Response.sendRedirect(url)

Once you application is returned (just null), Jersey will try to process the result in the "Responder.process(ContainerResponse)". In this step, it will use response to set status (204 no contents for your null return).

So the key point here is you must finalize/close response object before return from your service function. Otherwise, Jersey may overwrite your output.

Small tips on why "WebApplicationException" can overwrite Jersey repsponse. It is because org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.mapException() will use the "webApplicationException.getResponse()" as the return response result.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The problem is now long gone

Comment: This question is for me too as beginner of java RS before I figure out the above answer through hours searching, study the source code and debugging. That is why I list down my finding to save others time and avoid the wrong approach since I can't find 1 very clear answer before.